# A simple statistical test if a set of 1000 documents is homogeneous

Tags: testing, statistics, sample-size

I have a simple statistical question and hope someone here has a quick answer.

I have a set of 200 documents, each document should contain exactly 3 pages. My assumption is that all 100% of those documents have 3 pages. I want to take a sample that would statistically confirm that that set is homogeneous, which means that all documents have exactly 3 pages. If I find even one document in a sample having != 3 pages I would know my set is in-homogeneous.

How many documents do I have to look at to be 80% sure my set is homogeneous? Should I have more then 200 documents in my base set, for instance 1000?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i dont think that can be calculated from the given details, U should know the standard deviation of the base set.

Comment: I think this is what I want to test. If the base set is equally distributed.  (All documents have 3 pages)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test whether all documents are 3 pages. A statistical test will not help here. In most cases what you will have is a 5%, and 1% significance tests that the number of mean pages is 3. This means that there will be a 1 in 20, and 1 in a 100, respectively, chance that the pages might be different from 3.